# Crystal Report will not sum the duplicated record

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm working in Crystal Report 2008, And I have a data with like this:

```
  Date             KG         MT         SQM
 --------------------------------------------
01-01-2013       25000        25         
01-01-2013       15000        15
01-01-2013       15000        15            -----(duplicated)
01-02-2013       13000        13  
01-02-2013       12000        12  
01-03-2013       18000        18 
01-03-2013       33000        33
```

Then I tried to group it by date so the output is like this: so it's already removed the duplicated and sum the vlaue without a problem.

```
  Date             KG         MT         SQM
 --------------------------------------------
 01-01-2013       40000        40        55000 
 01-02-2013       25000        25        25000
 01-03-2013       51000        51        51000 

 TOTAL            116,000      116      131,000
```

Then I want to add the SQM, and when I sum it, it will sum all the record in the group also with duplicated record. 
(if you will sum the 3rd field, it also included in sum the duplicated record should be only '116,000' and not '131,000')

My question, how can I suppressed if duplicated and at the same time it will give me summary of the group to show the correct value?

Thanks,

Captain16

Comment: Where does that duplicated row come from? What are conditions to exclude it?

Comment: let say from KG, then I have a computation to make it SQM.

Comment: Sorry about my weak english, but I don't get it. I asked, why you have duplicate rows - is there some invalid query or have you duplicate data already in database or do you have multiple 1-N related tables in your report or what? And what means SQM?

Comment: I have duplicated rows from SQL Query, the SQM means Square Meter.

Comment: Can't you rework SQL query definition? I'm serious - it is always much better to fix root of problem, not consequences. Otherwise you could use running total field - sum only when this row is unique. For that you need very clear condition, how to exclude duplicates - IMO having similar KG values on same day doesn't qualify.

Comment: If it's from your SQL query and your SQL query is just returning those rows then update the SQL to "SELECT DISTINCT".  This will get rid of rows that are 100% duplicated.

Comment: Arvo's suggestion is bang on the money. If your query is causing spurious records you really want to address the query rather than jumping through hoops trying to fudge the data afterward